# How to use highlight.js with Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to use syntax highlighting with highlight.js in my rails application. The instructions for highlight.js are below (https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js):

The bare minimum for using highlight.js on a web page is linking to the library along with one of the styles and calling initHighlightingOnLoad:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles/default.css">
<script src="/path/to/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

I'm not certain where the above three should be placed. I've tried several possibilities. Presumably the first of the three, < link rel ... >, should be placed in the head of views/application/application.html.erb. And I think that the second of the three, < script src=... >, should be placed at the bottom of the file that contains the code that will be highlighted. I thought the third of the three, < script ... >, should go in the application.js file. In any case, I've tried this and several other possibilities, but I haven't been able to get the desired code highlighted in Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me..

- Create a file copy app\assets\javascripts\highlight.pack.js (Find file content here: https://highlightjs.org/download/)
- Create a file copy app\assets\stylesheets\github.scss (github.scss or your preference style, https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/). Don't forget import `@import "github";` into your file app\assets\stylesheets\application.scss
- Create a file app\assets\javascripts\highlights.js, and copy this follow code

If you are using turbolinks:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

If you are not using turbolinks:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

And done. Restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

You can place highlight.pack.js right in your app/assets/javascripts folder. It will be loaded into the Rails Asset Pipeline from there.

You should place default.css in your app/assets/stylesheets folder. It will also be loaded into the Rails Asset Pipeline from there (note you might need to rename this file to default.css.scss) I am unsure of whether or not you'll have to add the .scss file extension (maybe someone can edit this answer if they know - for now, rename it to default.css.scss).

...and then you should add this to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

In your view file you can use this:

```
<pre><code>
  Ruby Code Goes Here
</code></pre>
```

Comment: For the highlight.pack.js you say place it in app/assets/javascripts folder. Do you mean the application.js? I don't know how to put something in a folder. I put the default.css in the app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss. I receive an error when I load. This isn't too surprising as the css is only for selectors. Did you mean somewhere else? It follows the same format that I use for other fonts, so I would think it goes in the head of application.html.erb

Comment: I mean inside the folder that contains application.js (same thing goes for the css file - it should be in the stylesheets folder - not pasted into the application.css file)

Comment: How do I place something in a folder?

Comment: The easiest way for you is probably to Cut or Copy and then Paste the file into the folder. You could use terminal or command prompt as well if you're familiar with a command line interface.

Comment: I thought folders just have files. How do I put something into a folder?

Comment: Right click on the file (highlight.pack.js) and click copy. Then navigate to your the app/assets/javascripts folder (from Finder on a Mac or My Computer if you're on a Windows machine), open your javascripts folder, right click somewhere inside and click paste.

Comment: haha.. he thought that he will copy the code written in highlight.pack.js inside the folder ^_^ @JonRoby ... you will copy the file dude..

Comment: how can we specify it to highlight for swift?