# Syntax highlighting not working, tried code and pre code tags all showing up pink for some reason?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, highlight

Earlier I posted this:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/3r8n0f/how_to_get_keep_spaces_in_text/
```

I found that Ruby does save my spaces and line breaks so it worked great, but not I'm trying to use highlight.js and for some reason the text is going back to just being jumbled together and it's making it pink and I'm not sure why.

I'm using this as reference to install highlight.js( https://highlightjs.org/ ):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574032/how-to-use-highlight-js-with-rails
```

I've tried several different high lighting solutions this one seems the closet but now it's jumbling it again when I use

```
<code></code>
```

or

```
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

tags and making every thing pink. Can someone please take a look and explain why this is happening? I know I've posted here twice today now and that's probably annoying but I'm really trying to do my own easy thing now >.>; I've worked through several tutorials already and none have done much javascript really but I'm just so tired of following them.

Here's the link to github if you guys need to see it:

```
https://github.com/ilovemysillybanana/pastie
```

Here is the output I'm seeing when I bring up the page:

```
http://imgur.com/fsCfwZa
```

EDIT:
using

```
<pre></pre>
```

tags on the code preserves my spaces and line breaks, I learned that now but using

```
<code></code>
```

takes that away...

EDIT:

If I do this:

```
hljs.configure({useBR: true});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

It takes away the spaces, it seems like this thing only wants to make it pink and get rid of my spaces >.>

Switching the js part to this:

```
hljs.configure({useBR: true});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

Seems to still work even if I only try to render the code like this:

```
<code>
<%= program.code %>
</code>
```

So I guess it doesn't need

```
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

tags, it only needs

```
<code></code>
```

, but for some reason it still jumbling together and making it pink.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It isn't necessary to keep adding "Edit" tags in your question as you make changes. Instead, incorporate the information into your question as if you'd added it originally. We can see when changes occur, and, with sufficient points, we can see the changes themselves, making it unnecessary to flag them. Flagging only results in questions that are awkward and more difficult to read as the information is out of context and often out of place. Also, when referring to a page, don't use code-formatting for URLs. Instead, put them inline and markup will handle them for you.

Comment: "I've worked through several tutorials already and none have done much javascript really but I'm just so tired of following them." Please read and consider http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. Being tenacious and knowing how to research and teach ourselves is a core characteristic of a good programmer.

Comment: yeah, thanks for not helping dude. I've obviously been reading about getting javascript to freaking work. I even linked a site to the documentation.

Comment: While you may think I'm not trying to help, I am. Stack Overflow is manned by volunteers who do this on their free time. There are things we want to see and expect from those asking when we try to answer.  I'm trying to help you get help based on those things. A link is not proof. What didn't work about what you read and tried? What else have you read? Help us understand so we don't have to ask a lot of questions for clarification.